# Re-evaluating the for loop condition for each run

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

I have a `for` loop to list the files in a directory and then based on their names, moves them to various appropriate folders.

Say there are 300 files like below:

1. Prefix_filename1_suffix1_date.txt - 100 files
2. Prefix_filename101_suffix2_date.txt - 150 files
3. Prefix_filename251_suffix3_date.txt - 50 files

I would only be knowing the prefix and the folder location of files in the beginning of the loop:

```
cd folder_location
for f in $(ls ${file_prefix}*); do
```

The file names would be known to me after I enter the `for` loop -- that is one challenge.

I use a *regex* to find a suffix common to all files, then use `awk` to get a file name between the prefix and suffix.  So to use *regex* and `awk` I need the file names to go through the `for` loop.

While processing these files I move all similar files together, so (if there were three sets of files), the files might be moved in 3 runs (let's say the 1st, 101th and 251th ), and the other 297 runs don't do anything because there are no files to process, because it has listed 300 files -- originally the loop runs 300 times.

How do I avoid this?   And make the loop to run just 3 times.

Comment: Can you post your for-loop?

Comment: for f in $(ls ${file_prefix}*); do

Comment: I do a cd folder_location before the for loop

Comment: And what do you mean with "The file names would be known to me after I enter the for loop"?

Comment: I use a regex to find a suffix which is common to all files then use awk to get the file name between prefix and suffix. So to use regex and awk I need the file names to go through the for loop

Comment: And why can't you pre-compute the regexes (for all three groups) outside the loop? Then you actually wouldn't need the loop at all and can simply copy with a glob-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the filenames only have those underscores in the places given,  (not in the *prefix*, *name*, or *suffix*), just `cut` the third field, (i.e. the *suffix*), and `sort -u`, and we have our three *suffix*es.  Pipe that to a loop, and `mv` the matching files to their *ad hoc* subdirectories.

```
cd folder_location
echo ${file_prefix}*.txt | cut -d '_' -f 3 | sort -u | \
while read suffix ; do
    [ -d ${suffix} ] || mkdir ${suffix}
    mv ${file_prefix}*_${suffix}_*.txt ${suffix}/
done
```